# Calculate rolling difference in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rolling-computation

I'm trying to do a rolling difference in a dataset. I have a table like this:

```
Year  Count
2017  5
2017  6
2017  7
2017  6
2017  8
```

And I would like to get a column for difference, which is calculated from the 5th row onward. So it will look like this

```
Index  Count  Diff
1      5      NA
2      6      NA
3      7      NA
4      6      NA
5      8      NA
6      3      -2
7      4      -2
8      9      2
9      2      -4
10     1      -7
```

Right now I just subset the count column and combine with zeros for the calculation. Is there a more tidy way of doing this?

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
a <- df$Count[1:5]
b <- rep(0,5)
df$Count1 <- c(b,a)
df$Diff <- df$Count - df$Count1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `lag` from `dplyr` as follows

```
df$Diff <- df$Count - dplyr::lag(df$Count, n = 5)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Diff := Count - shift(Count, 5)]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use base `R`:

```
df$Diff <- c( rep(NA, 5), tail(df$Count, -5) - head(df$Count, -5) )
```

Here is a variant with `diff()`

```
df$Diff <- c(rep(NA, 5), diff(df$Count, lag=5))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `diff.zoo` and `na.fill` from the zoo package:

```
library(zoo)
transform(df, diff = na.fill(diff(zoo(Count), 5, na.pad = TRUE), fill = 0))
```

Alternately, `rollapplyr` from zoo:

```
transform(df, diff = rollapplyr(Count, 5 + 1, diff, 5, fill = 0))
```